# How to Drop/Create Database name that has upper-case letter?

Tags: postgresql, psql

for example my `Postgresql`  database name is `Ajp`

i cannot drop/create the db with this name ie. `Ajp`

my scripts for drop is

```
cd /D D:\\Apps
cd RSTAR PGSQL DOTCONNECT
cd bin
cd Debug
cd PG
psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE  Ajp "
```

while executing this i got this error

> D:\Apps\RSTAR PGSQL DOTCONNECT\bin\Debug\PG>psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c "DR
>   OP DATABASE  Ajp "
>   ERROR:  database "ajp" does not exist

i tried `psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE  'Ajp' "` (db name within quotes)

again got error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Ajp'"
>   LINE 1: DROP DATABASE  'Ajp'

how fix this problem ?? (please don't comment that `change your dbname to lower-case`)

`using : "PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit"`

**the solution for this problem is below**

- Sholud use escape character `\`
- `psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE \"Ajp\";"`

  see the [below comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905515/how-to-drop-create-database-name-that-has-upper-case-letter#comment36811674_23905616)

Comment: I *will* comment on your usage of mixed-case identifiers: this is a really good example why you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 55):

SQL identifiers that are case-sensitive need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
DROP DATABASE  "Ajp";
```

Not sure if they are properly preserved on Windows if you pass them through the commandline though.

You might need to put that into a SQL script and pass the script name to psql.

For details on valid identifiers please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: still the same `ERROR:  database "ajp" does not exist`

Comment: @user3682599: then you didn't enter the statement as shown. The message "*database "ajp" does not exist*" clearly means you either used `drop database ajp` or `drop database "ajp"` but **not** `drop database "Ajp"` (note the upper case `A`. Or the other alternative is that the `"` was somehow swallowed by the Windows commandline. What happens if you enter the statement *manually* at the `psql` prompt (not passing it through `-c`)

Comment: No i have tried `DROP DATABASE  "Ajp";`   please [see this](http://s2.postimg.org/xzkby4ozt/drop.jpg)

Comment: @user3682599: then there is something you are not telling us because what I wrote will certainly work *if* you really have a database name `"Ajp"`. What does `\l` give you in `psql` (please add the output to your question, don't post it as a comment)

Comment: @user3682599 proper escape on windows' cmd.exe (which is also used to execute batch files) is `psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE \"Ajp\""`

Comment: @user3682599 it isn't another answer, that's just the way windows' command line works. You can accept this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will come across this question using PowerShell, which also requires the backslash and double quote. Both need escaped with a tick. (thanks pozs)

(Reading from an Xml config file)

```powershell
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
[xml]$config = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Installer\Config\install.config.xml"
$securePass = Read-Host "Enter password for postgres account" -AsSecureString
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securePass)
$pgPass = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
$env:PGPASSWORD = $pgPass
# Skip to here for usage:
$dropDbCmd = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `\`"" + $config.Settings.dbName + "`\`";"
.\psql.exe -c $dropDbCmd -d "postgres" -p $config.Settings.dbPort -U "postgres"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's old question but, it may help someone else.
Try this:

```sh
echo "CREATE DATABASE \\"DataBaseName\\" ;" | psql --host=xxxx.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=xxxx@xxxx --dbname=postgres
```